# iterate through jquery code

Tags: jquery, slide, loops

i built a big table,and i want to iterate through some classes name on it to use a jquery effect(slideToggle),but when i tried to make a loop via For,nothing occur

html:

```
         <tr>
                        <td dir="ltr"><a href="">array_push()</a></td>
                        <td>اضافة عنصر او أكثر لنهاية المصفوفة</td>
                        <td>530</td>
                        <td class="example2">12.5</td></td>
                        <td>12.5</td>

                </tr>

         <thead>
        <tr> 
        <th colspan="5" rowspan="3" class="slide2" >
       <pre class="prettyprint lang-php ">
$a=array("Dog","Cat");
array_push($a,"Horse","Bird");
print_r($a);

       </pre>
        </th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
```

i want iterate through class name (example,slide) to take a number like example1,example2................

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for (var i=1;i<=120;i++){
    $(".example[i]").click(function(){


        $(".slide[i]").slideToggle(500);

        })

    }

    })
```

Comment: thanks tats for ur advice,and html code is like that,it's just a table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not appending the index to the class.  Look at the below code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    for (var i=1;i<=120;i++){
    $(".example" + i).click(function(){
      $(".slide" + i).slideToggle(500);
    })
  }
});
```